# Katalon would not start chrome with a profile being set using WEB UI args

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, automation, katalon-studio

After downloading KCU and adding args on List Property Builder accordingly to the documention -https://docs.katalon.com/docs/katalon-studio/record-and-spy/webui-record-and-spy-utilities/katalon-compact-utility-for-katalon-studio#ariaid-title1

The Record and Spy and Test Execution do open a correct chrome profile, but fail and display an error:
https://imgur.com/a/2oN5o34

Also, my Chrome is 121.0.6167.86 and chromeDriver is 121.0.6167.85.
I'm not sure if it causes the issue, but integrated tool for updating chromeDriver does download .85 specifically.

Any advices or help would be appreciated :)

I did not try to downgrade chrome. Hopefully, the fix may not include of reintstall of anything